# A simple answer

Tags: british-english

I am sorry for the naive question. What is a common way to answer to something like 'Good weekend' or 'Have a nice day'? I have recently heard the expression 'And you'. Is it common in British English? I would say 'You too' or 'I wish you the same', but 'And you' sounds strange to me. Thank you!

Comment: As a native American speaker, this sounds slightly odd to me as well.  I would expect to hear "And to you." or perhaps "Same to you."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these are good ways to answer. I'd be most likely to say, "you, too," also. "I wish you the same" sounds kind of formal, but is especially polite and emphatic.

Both "you, too" and "and you" imply approximately the same thing and are leaving out similar parts of the sentence:

> And you (have a nice day or a good weekend, too).

> You (have a nice day or a good weekend), too.

It's a little odd, because the implied "you" in the imperative is the part of the sentence that gets explicitly stated in these answers.